# $log_1(x)$ existance

Tags: soft-question, logarithms

I was looking at the equation $2^x=29$ and I saw that it was the same thing as asking $2=\sqrt[x]{29}$ So $$ 1^x=27$$ but is also $$1=\sqrt[x]{27}$$  I also saw that $\sqrt[x]{27}$ goes to 1 as  gets bigger. Which can be expressed as $log_1(27)=lim_{x  \to \infty} \sqrt[x]{27}$So does that mean that $log_1(x)$ could exist?

Comment: **(1)** $\;1^x=1\,$ for $\,\forall x \ge 0\,\;$ **(2)** $\;1 \ne 27\,$

Comment: @dxiv $1\neq 27$? Not with *that* attitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sqrt[x]{27}=27^{1/x}$

And

$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x}=0$

So

$\lim_{x\to\infty} 27^{1/x} = 1$

Therefore:

$\nexists x\in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\sqrt[x]{27} =1$

Note this follows for any positive real $\gt 1.$

Comment: You’re not wrong but your proof isn’t valid. Simply having $f(x)\to n$ does not mean $\not\exists x:f(x)=n$.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor in general you are correct, but in this specific case, it should be clear by considering the properties (namely the convergence properties) of n-th roots that this works

Comment: Touché ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$